# How to pay AWS bills

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an unpaid bill in AWS (I've been using Free Tier so far) and I already added my debit card to AWS.

[image]

However, when I select bills, I have no option for paying it, I can only download it in PDF.

[image]

If I click the *Make Payment* button, it takes me to Payment History (where I can't see the previously paid bill).

[image]

As I recall, I paid a bill a year ago (hence the added debit card), but it seems they changed something.
How could I do that?

Comment: What happens if you click that blue `Make Payment` button? Is that for something else?

Comment: Contact Amazon?

Comment: @MC10 See the update question.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the card as the default: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment.html#designate-default

Comment: @MC10 It says _Current Default_. I think it is properly set.

Comment: @Nestor, In your last screenshot, under **actions column** it says **contact us** for you while for me it says **pay now**. So you must contact them

Comment: [Have a look at the screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nlLUO.png)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Thanks, I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Amazon Customer Services and they've helped me. For the record, the payment was charged on my debit card automatically so I didn't have to use any pay button.